# Continuous derivative vs Continuous partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Firstly, suppose $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ has all continuous partial derivative. I believe I have proved that this imply continuous derivative. Please tell me if this is actually true.

For its converse, I $guess$ that having continuous derivative imply having all continuous partial derivative, but I have no idea how to prove it. Please give me some directions. Thanks.

Comment: You have to specify, what the total derivative is with respect to.

Comment: For instance, if $f:f(x,y)$ and $x$ and $y$ are independent of each other, then $\frac {df} {dx} = \frac {\partial{f}} {\partial{x}}$, and thus the total derivative is indeed continuous.

Comment: Actually $f'$ is a also R^n to R^m fucntion, i.e. like a m*n matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess we should be a little careful here. By definition, the derivative of $f$ at $x\in \mathbb R^{n}$ is the linear transformation $f'(x):\mathbb R^{n}\to \mathbb R^{m}$ such that $$\tag 1\left | \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h}{h} \right |\to 0$$ as $$\vert h\vert \to 0$$ and we know that, for $1\leq j\leq n$ $$\tag 2 f'(x)e_{j}=\left ( \frac{\partial f_{1}(x)}{\partial x_{j}},\frac{\partial f_{2}(x)}{\partial x_{j}},\cdots ,\frac{\partial f_{m}(x)}{\partial x_{j}} \right )$$

To say $f'$ is continuous at $x$ means that the function $f':\mathbb R^{n}\to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^{n},\mathbb R^{m})$ given by $x\mapsto f'(x)$ is continuous. Then, we must have

$\left \| f'(y)-f'(x) \right \|\to 0$ as $\vert y-x\vert\to 0$ and so, in partcular,

$\vert (f'(y)-f'(x))e_{j}\vert \to 0$ as $\vert y-x\vert\to 0$. Then, using $(2)$, we get $$\tag 3 \left | \left ( \frac{\partial f_{1}(y)}{\partial x_{j}}-\frac{\partial f_{1}(x)}{\partial x_{j}},\frac{\partial f_{2}(y)}{\partial x_{j}}-\frac{\partial f_{2}(x)}{\partial x_{j}},\cdots ,\frac{\partial f_{m}(y)}{\partial x_{j}}-\frac{\partial f_{m}(x)}{\partial x_{j}} \right ) \right |\to 0 $$ as $\vert y-x\vert \to 0$ and $(3)$ now says that $$\tag 4 \left | \frac{\partial f_{i}(y)}{\partial x_{j}}-\frac{\partial f_{i}(x)}{\partial x_{j}} \right |\to 0$$ as $\vert y-x\vert \to 0$ for $1\leq i\leq m;1\leq j\leq n$ which is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both implications are true. Since you only ask about the converse, note that $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x_i} (x) = \Bbb d f (x) (e_i)$, with $e_i = (0, \dots , 0, 1, 0, \dots , 0)$, the $1$ being on the $i$-th position (this should be written as a column, in fact, but please accept it as a row for my easier typing). Since $x \mapsto \Bbb d f (x)$ is continuous by assumption, applying it on the fixed vector $e_i$ will again produce a continuous function, which is what you want.